# Evaluate how many times a double sum is calculated

Tags: sum

Assume I have a double sum (I cannot figure out how to write latex-code here), and a variable`c` which is being calculated in each iteration i.e

sum_{i=1}^n sum_{j>i}^n c

How many times are the sums being evaluated, i.e how many `c` do we have when the sums are finished? I would say that we have `n(n-1)c` (since the outer-sum runs n times, and the inner runs (n-1) times) but if I write some quick code to do it numerically i get `n(n-1)/2`

```py
n=5
c=0

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(i+1,n+1):
        print(f"j: {j}")
        print(f"i: {i}")
        c+=1


print(c)
print(n*(n-1)/2)
```

Comment: The inner sum generally does not have n-1 instances. It depends on i, and it ranges from 0 to n-1. The average is (n-1)/2.

Comment: Aah... True that! I totally forgot the incremental of j. Thanks!